# How to save the user's attachment discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command that saves the attachment that the user has sent to a directory

I tried doing this:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def upload(self, ctx):
        dev_ids = ['some_id', 'some_id']
        
        if ctx.author.id not in dev_ids: return
        
        if len(ctx.message.attachments) <= 0:
            return await ctx.send('No attachments attached/detected.')
        
        attachment = ctx.message.attachments[0]
        filename = f'uploads_{ctx.author.id}_{attachment.id}'
        
        try:
            await attachment.save(f'assets/uploads/{filename}.jpeg')

            await ctx.send('Saved photo')
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f'An Eror Occured: {e}')
```

I got this error instead:

```
An Eror Occured: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'assets/uploads/uploads_508475828493877258_943437823749550100.jpeg'
```

Although the directory does exist

Comment: Are you sure that the working directory is where the directory `assets` exists?

Comment: oops should've known that oh no lmao, thank you anyways